# Passing commands with double quotes to subprocess.call in python

Tags: python, shell, ffmpeg, subprocess

I want to pass a command to a Linux machine running ffmpeg using python containing a double quotes. That's my script:

```
drawtext = "drawtext=\"fontfile=DejaVuSans: text='Random Name': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=20: y=20\""
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-v", "error", "-i", input.mp4, "-vf", drawtext, output.mp4])
```

If I print the drawtext variable this is the output:

```
drawtext="fontfile=DejaVuSans: text='Reference Image': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=20: y=20"
```

And this is my error in ffmpeg:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x564ad79f99c0] [Eval @ 0x7ffd41131810] Invalid chars '"' at the end of expression '20"'
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x564ad79f99c0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawtext_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

If I execute the following command in Linux shell it works just fine:

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 10 -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=DejaVuSans: text='Random Name': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=20: y=20" output.mp4
```

Comment: When you call `ffmpeg ... drawtext="fontfile..."`, the argument that ffmpeg sees is `drawtext=fontfile`.  That is, the shell removes the double quotes.  Don't include them.

Comment: Perhaps it's clearer if you realize that when you invoke `ffmpeg drawtext="fontfile"`, the shell invokes exactly the same process as when you invoke `ffmpeg "drawtext=fontfile"` or `ffmpeg dra"wtex"t=fon"tfile"` or `ffmpeg drawtext=fontfile`.

Comment: it works @WilliamPursell. Thanks!

Comment: spent over an hour trying to figure out why it worked in bash, but not when using subprocess.call removing the double quotes from drawtext did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

One way for executing can be creating a shell script with the content as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=DejaVuSans: text='Random Name': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=20: y=20" output.mp4
```

You can then save this as `script.sh` and then you can call the script as follows:

```
import subprocess; subprocess.call(`./script.sh`; shell=True)
```

Comment: yes, but I prefer not to mix python with bash scripting. Actually @WilliamPursell gave me a very good tip, which works drawtext = `"drawtext=fontfile=... x=20: y=20"` so I just removed the quotations around the fontfile and of course the `\` from the line and then the subprocess.call line works as expected.